# Can't fadeOut span or image but I can fadeOut DIV?

Tags: javascript

Newbie in javascript.. Need a little help.

I have a SPAN or IMG that I want to fadeOut using javascript. However nothing happens when I do this:

```
// HTML
<span id='test_one'>Span Text Here</span>
<img src='img_src_here' id='test_two'>

// JavaScript
$(test_one).fadeOut();
$(test_two).fadeOut();
```

But if I do this, it functions correctly:

```
// HTML
<div id='test_one'>Span Text Here</div>

// JavaScript
$(test_one).fadeOut();
```

Am I just making or a silly mistake or am I going insane?

Thanks
Coulton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, your selector is incorrect:

```
$('#test_one').fadeOut();
```

Note that it should be a string (so single or double quotes) and use '#' to select by id. [Documentation of selectors can be found on the jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

This should work:

```
// HTML
<span id='test_one'>Span Text Here</span>
<img src='img_src_here' id='test_two'>

// JavaScript
$('#test_one').fadeOut();
$('#test_two').fadeOut();
```

---

**Edit**

As to why it works with the `div` but not the `img` or `span`, I'm not entirely clear but as @Steve pointed out, it is possible to reference elements by using their `id`s as global variables. However, this is non-standard behaviour and only some browsers (notoriously IE) perform this mapping of element `id`s to the global namespace. IE also allows fetching of named elements via `getElementById()`! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925000/strange-ie-error-between-javascript-global-variable-and-element-with-name-attri/3925036#3925036) and [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/getElementById#compatibilitysection). I would suggest not depending on this behaviour.

Comment: While this is more correct, I believe his version will still work, as you can reference elements in the DOM by simply using their IDs as if they were global variables.

Comment: It works. Thanks! Can't accept your answer now, have to wait 5 minutes. ha.

Comment: @Steve I don't believe that's standard behaviour - it seems to be specific to IE/Opera/Chrome where elements with id or name are accessible via the global namespace - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925000/strange-ie-error-between-javascript-global-variable-and-element-with-name-attri/3925036#3925036) and [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/getElementById#compatibilitysection). I would suggest not depending on this behaviour.

Comment: @phpnerd211 No worries, head on back later :)

Comment: @no.good.at.coding: It works in Safari too (i.e. WebKit). I think it's extremely bad coding practice, but theoretically if using one of these browsers (i.e. anything except Gecko/Firefox), it should work.

Comment: @Steve Point taken. But since it *is* non-standard, perhaps it's best to forget that it even exists :) (unless troubleshooting or restricted to only browsers that support it, of course). But anyway, since you pointed it out, all of who made the effort now know about it!

Comment: Anonymous downvote is pointless and not helping anyone, if you think there's something wrong, please point it out.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, which library are you using? jQuery? (The `fadeOut()` method is not built in to JavaScript.)

Try setting the CSS property of your `<span>` or `<img>` to `display: block` or `display:inline-block`. This should make the fade out work. The reason it works on your `<div>` element is that it is a block element by default. `<span>` and `<img>` elements are displayed inline by default.

Comment: Strictly speaking <img> is a display:inline-block element as it has its own box. And <span>, indeed, is display:inline element as it has no box but rather is a list of boxes (glyphs and inline-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

You must use the selectors efficiently like this
for "id" use:

```
$('#myId').fadeOut();
```

for classes like this:

```
$('.myClass').fadeOut();
```

and so on....

Answer (score 1):

In your styles add this:

```
span#test_one { display:inline-block; }
```

And of course:

```
  $("#test_one").fadeOut();
```

The code you've provided will work only in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a stupid mistake (we all make them), your selector should be `$('#test_two')`

Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/ku8sa/

Comment: @Steve Harrison Odd, that is good to know, though I only changed that and it seemed to work (maybe his version is deprecated?).