# Geting a value from select box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer-8

**I've got a simple select input and I'm using jQuery's .val() to get the selection from it.**

For some reason, it is throwing a "Object doesn't support this property or method" error in Internet Explorer 8, the first error I've ever seen jQuery actaully throw.

I've replicated this error at http://jsfiddle.net/gWvwS

What am I doing wrong? Seems pretty straight forward to me...

Comment: Choose another name for your variable, or add `var` before it. Is your problem solved? http://jsfiddle.net/gWvwS/5/

Comment: Yes, it appears that even just changing the id/name of the input works. But what is the reason display_entry_form won't work?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it. What version of jQuery are you using in your project?

Comment: @John, I have explained it below. I am not fully sure about `var` though.

Comment: Put a var in front. [Internet Explorer gives you different behavior with regards to scoped variables, hence var is good practice][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925000/strange-ie-error-between-javascript-global-variable-and-element-with-name-attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document contains an element with name `display_entry_form`. In IE, named elements are globally accessible through their name. So, you have to either use `var` (to declare a new, local variable<sup>[Need verification]</sup>), or choose another name.

```
var other_name = $('#display_entry_form').val();
alert(other_name);
```

**Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gWvwS/5/**

Comment: Adding var works for me. Thanks for the explanation as to why!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var isplay_entry_form = $('#display_entry_form').val();
alert(isplay_entry_form);
```

`display_entry_form` on the global window is actually the element. It's much less known, because it's really bad and shouldn't be used. So you are overwriting it in IE.

Fixed Example for IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/gWvwS/7/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript variables with the same name as DOM elements  are not supported by IE. It appears that IE uses a common mechanism for addressing DOM elements by id and addressing javascript variables. Which means that whichever object (DOM element or javascript var) is declared later in the source is the one that gets used. This will likely cause an "object does not support this property or method" error when you try to access your javascript variable. ([source](http://www.karlstanley.net/blog/?p=5))

This should work:

```
display_entry_form_value = $('#display_entry_form > option:selected').val();
alert(display_entry_form_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it has to do with, that value belongs to option, not to select.

Try

```
$('select#display_entry_form option:selected').val();
```

Comment: Well, just an attempt :) And now I see that he actually used option:selected - I am not sure if I had overlooked it or if he changed it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I updated jsfiddle to correct code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gWvwS/6/

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` tag doesn't have a `value` attribute, but rather a `selectedIndex` attribute.